# Conocer la propiedad name de un input con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo la duda sobre como obtener la propiedad name que le asigno a un input en el interior de un formulario, para imprimirlo en pantalla. Mi código del formulario sería el siguiente :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombres" name="nombre" required placeholder="Nombre">
        <br>
    <label>Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required/>
        <br>
    <label>Nombre de usuario</label>    
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario"  required/>
        <br>
    <label>Correo</label>
        <input type="email" name="correo"   placeholder="Correo"    required/>
        <br>
    <label>Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña" required/>     
        <br>

    <input type="submit" name="registro" value="registrar" onclick="recibir()" />

</form>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la atención brindada.

Answer (score 3):

Podrias intentsar esto:

```
<input type="text" id="nombres" name="nombre" required placeholder="Nombre">
alert(document.getElementById("nombres").name)
```

Esto lo puedes aplicar para cada input.

Comment: Lo voy a probrar, gracias de antemano

Comment: Si, te funciona lo puedes marcar como respuesta :)

Comment: Funciono estupendo, gracias.

Comment: Una consulta... ¿y si tengo mas de un id?, osea, si quiero que la función sea mas genérica, y pueda ejecutarse con diferentes ids? pero sin indicarlos explícitamente?. Desde ya muchas gracias.